# Replace multiple strings between characters in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to replace strings with variables in the same way that Python string formatting works.

The string will be in a similar format to:

```
string = 'Replace $name$ as well as $age$ and $country$';
```

And I'd like to have a regex operation that will return and array:

```
['name', 'age', 'country'] or ['$name$', '$age$', '$country$']
```

So that I can map it to object keys:

```
{
 name    : 'Bob',
 age     :  50,
 country : 'US'
}
```

I've seen solutions using string concatenation but I need a solution using regex because
I have to rely on strings containing these variables.

Comment: Should be simple enough. What have you tried so far? What is acceptable in one of your token names?

Comment: Anything really, as long as it isn't expected as actual content, so a single character would do as well as a combination.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this:

```
var string = 'Replace $name$ as well as $age$ and $country$';
var arr = [];
string.replace(/\$(.+?)\$/g, function(m,g1){ arr.push(g1); return m; });
console.log(arr); // desired output
```

Comment: That `.+` should be `.+?` to make it not greedy.

Comment: @MattBurland, yeah I knew! Done

Comment: @Matt or you could use `[^$]+`

Comment: @TomFenech: Personally I prefer the non-greedy `?`, but what you suggest would work as well. Really don't know if there's an actual benefit to one versus the other.

Comment: It would be nice if this solution allowed for an escape character so you could do something like `var string = 'Price: \$$price$'.